Why doesn't this compile unless the document has a signature/byte order mark?
If I start a new project in Visual studio and I write the following (this is from a github repo by the way):
#include <cstdint>
static bool is_unicode_Lo_char(uint32_t c) {
    // open a hole for carrot
    if (c == U'') return true;
}

int main()
{


}


Some Unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current
codepage. Do you want to resave this file as Unicode in order to
maintain your data?

If I hit 'no' I get a compiler error saying:

"Too many characters in constant"

on the line where the carrot is.
So I save the document with encoding:
Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage - 65001.

I still get the error, same error.
Then I save the document with:
Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage - 65001.

Then it compiles. The difference being that it added EF BB BF to the beginning of the file. Then it compiles fine. I'm wondering why this is. What does saving the document as UTF-8 without signature mean if no one can recognise that it's UTF-8? How can you even recognise UTF-8? Surely it's not if there's any byte with the MSB set because above 127 values for ASCII/ANSI do exist. Do I have to save with the byte order mark? Is saving with byte order mark generally encouraged?

Please choose either C or C++... The two languages are not the same thing.

What compiler gives you this error? MSVC might need /utf-8 flag.

The question itself is good, but I am generally against BOM in code. I don't know what the standard practice is for using BOM when developing code in non-English languages. In the English repositories I work with, BOM is not desirable. It can mess stuff up. I don't let any code through review that introduces a BOM. Any Unicode character literals should be implemented as escape sequences.

In general, UTF-8 ought to be used without the signature BOM (q.v. UTF-8 Everywhere).  But it does mean that the entire pipeline needs to be on the same page (pun alert) regarding the encoding of the text stream (q.v. /utf-8).

MSFT thinks its compiler should still be able to compile source code that was written 30+ years ago.  Nobody else does this, but such is the burden of closed source.  So it assumes program text was written in the current code page, unless overridden with /utf8 or a BOM.  Avoid the issue entirely with c == U'\x1f955'

MSVC needs /utf-8 compiler switch if source file has no BOM.
See the similar thread: "error C2015: too many characters in constant" for a char32_t literal
Also see blog: New Options for Managing Character Sets in the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler

If the file does not have a BOM, we try to detect both little-endian
and big-endian forms of UTF-16 encoding by looking at the first 8
bytes. If the file looks like UTF-16 we will treat it as if there was
a UTF-16 BOM on the file. If there is no BOM and it doesn’t look like
UTF-16, then we use the current code page (result of a call to GetACP)
to convert the bytes on disk into UTF-8. This may or may not be
correct depending on how the file was actually encoded and what
characters it contains. If the file is actually encoded as UTF-8, this
will never be correct as the system code page can’t be set to CP_UTF8.


Note that the /utf-8 option is equivalent to setting both /source-charset and /execution-charset to UTF-8.  In some cases, it might be preferable to set just /source-charset to UTF-8.

The text you quoted says the "system code page can't be set to CP_UTF8."  But the documentation for the /utf-8 option says it uses the "current user code page," which I believe can be set to CP_UTF8.  Granted, it's better to be explicit.  (I've never understood why the Unicode standard discourages marking UTF-8 files as such.  I find the given rationale for that unpersuasive.)

@AdrianMcCarthy If the byte order mark is looked for when first opening/reading the file, what if it's actually ASCII or a something else whose first bytes just happen to match the byte order mark?

@Zebrafish: The byte order mark (in any encoding) is not valid ASCII.  Although unlikely, the byte order mark could be a valid sequence in some code pages, but that's not only a problem with UTF-8 but also with UTF-16 and UTF-32, which absolutely need a BOM.

@AdrianMcCarthy When you say it's not valid ASCII, do you say that because any values over 127 aren't valid ASCII? What if it's extended ASCII? Is that not really much, or at all?

It involves a new problem. Did this blog answer your original question?
